# Materials not rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I have been searching online for the answer to this for a few hours now and I just can't get this resolved on my own.

The materials are not showing up in the final render, they show as gray scale but show up colored in everything else. I have made sure the materials are made in Cycles render and that there are no over riding of materials in the renderlayers tab.

[image: BlenderSS]

Answer (score 2):

You are filtering color channels in the *Image Viewer*, currently only the red channel is being displayed.

Return to *Color and Alpha* mode, your image is fine, no need to re-render.

[image]

Comment: I knew it had to be something so simple! This resolved my issue, Thank you for your time!

Comment: Don't just thank in the comments, if an answer helped you upvote it; and if you feel it solved your problem consider marking it as accepted.